# Strange directory structure after upgrade cassandra dse to 4.8.5

Tags: cassandra, upgrade, datastax, opscenter

I've just upgraded my dse cluster to the newest version of dse (4.8.5).
After upgrade and first backup taken by opscenter i noticed that dir of my keyspace has strange subdirectories. Before it was only subdirectories with name corresponding to name of column family, but now there are extra subdirectories which names begins with the column family name and end with some id. For exapmle:
 adresse
 adresse-489b600c299634da953e3102af80b02b
but i have only column family: adresse.
Could you explain this strange behaviour?

Thanks
Przemek

Answer (score 0):

What is your previous version of Cassandra? Are you aware of columnFamily id?

Comment: My previous version was: DSE 4.6.0 cassandra 2.0.11.83.

Comment: I found answer. In Cassandra 2.0 dir for snapshots was: data_directory_location/keyspace_name/table_name/snapshots/snapshot_name but in cassandra 2.1 is: data_directory_location/keyspace_name/table_name-UUID/snapshots/snapshot_name

Answer (score 0):

I found answer. In Cassandra 2.0 dir for snapshots was: data_directory_location/keyspace_name/table_name/snapshots/snapshot_name but in cassandra 2.1 is: data_directory_location/keyspace_name/table_name-UUID/snapshots/snapshot_name